# C++ vector implementation push_front error

Tags: c++, stdvector

When making a basic vector implementation in C++, I get a problem in the `push_front` problem (below) `_Alloc` is the allocator class, `content_` is the pointer to the data, `size_` and `capacity_` are what they say, and `empty()` is a function checking if the pointer is empty or not. (`pointer` type is `value_type *`)

*Test:*

```
vector<int> v;
for (int i = 1; i <= 25; ++i)
{
    v.push_front(i);
}
for (auto &a : v)
{
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

*Output:*

> 25
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24
>
> 24

---

```
_Myt &push_front(const value_type &_Value)
{
    if (++size_ >= capacity_)
    {
        reserve(capacity_ * 2);
    }
    int pos = 1;
    if (!empty())
    {
        pointer tmp = content_; // for the values
        for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i, ++pos)
        {
            _Alloc().destroy(i); // destroy the current
            _Alloc().construct(&content_[pos], buf[pos - 1]); // add the value in into the next position
        }
    }
    _Alloc().construct(&content_[0], _Value); // put _Value to the front
    return *this;
}
```

---

What is the problem (with my code)?

Comment: Your "movement" is destroying an object *before* it is moved. Worse, it is then laying the object just destroyed down on top of the one in front of it, then moving to that and repeating the process. Also, `buf` is a mystery variable, as it is neither declared here nor describe in your post, and `tmp` is completely unused, though initialized. The destroy-overlay is particularly nasty, btw, as it not only is copy-constructing from an indeterminate value (you just destroyed it), it is also *not* destroying the thing about to be overlaid.

Comment: Unrelated, your code is not exception safe, and also there's standard algorithms for the moving part.  `std::copy`, `std::move`, and `std::rotate`.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c34be530f9b6a11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code is very confusing, because you're using two
variables in the copy loop.  And since `pos` always indexes one
behind the iterator `i`, you destruct the value before copying
it up one.  Which will work if the type has a trivial
destructor, but won't work in general.  To do the loop
correctly, you'll have to use assignment when both the target
and the source are constructed elements, and the copy
constructor otherwise.

But the biggest problem is that you're copying in the wrong
direction.  You need to copy from highest to lowest for this
overlapping copy to work.

EDIT:

Roughly speaking: the simplest implementation will contain three
pointers: `begin`, `end` and `top`, corresponding to the start
of the data, the end of the initialized data and the top of the
available (already allocated) memory.  To shift everything back
one element (supposing not empty):

```
std::uninitialized_copy( end - 1, end, end );
++ end;
std::copy_backward( begin, end - 2, end - 1 );
```

(Note that this is generic.  Change `1` to however many you have
to shift back, and `begin` to the insertion point, and you've
got the generic insert.  On the other hand, it *doesn't* use the
`construct` function of the allocator; for that, you'd have to
implement your own version of `uninitialized_copy`.)

Also note that `end` is changed *after* the new element has been
constructed, but before the `copy_backward`.  For the reasoning
behind this: think of what will happen if the construction of
the new element throws an exception.  Or if one of the assigns
throws an exception.  And then you try to destruct the object.
If you increment `end` too early, you'll try to destruct an
object that wasn't fully constructed; to late, and you'll not
destruct all of the objects which have been fully constructed.

If you want to write out the copy (for pedogogical reasons):

```
_Alloc().construct( end, *(end - 1) );
++ end;
for ( auto current = end - 2; current != begin; -- current ) {
    *(current + 1) = (current);
}
```

The important thing is 1) to construct into the newly allocated
elements, but to assign (`copy`) when moving one element to
another already constructed element, and 2) to be sure that you
never move a value into an element which hasn't itself been
moved yet.  This second point means that when shifting down, you
start at the lower addresses (which will correspond to the
elements being removed, and so can be overwritten), and when
shifting up, you start at the higher elements (the highest of
which will be moved into new memory, thus copy constructed).

Comment: Could you provide an example for that please?

Comment: @Joseph OK.  I've added some code.  And if I were you... I'd get it working without the added complexity of allocators first, and then go back and modify it to use the allocators.

Comment: @Joseph One other important point: make sure that you leave the object in a stable state if an exception occurs.  This means, for example, not incrementing `end` until the construction of the new object has finished (but incrementing it after that and anything else which might throw).  I've edited the code to correct for this.

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop that copies the values (`for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i, ++pos)`) you start at the beginning, moving the first element to the second, then take that same element from the second position to the third, etc.

Also note that you destroy each element before you copy it to the next slot resulting in undefined behavior.